# HTTP аутентификация не пропускает даже при правильно введенных данных

Tags: php, http, аутентификация

Здравствуйте. Вот пример моей аутентификации:

```
<?php
class Authentication
{
    public static function authenticate()
    {
        if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ||
                !isset($_SERVER['PATH_AUTH_PW'])||
                ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!= "admin")||
                ($_SERVER['PATH_AUTH_PW']!= "admin"))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm= "Rest-api"');
            exit('Sorry, you must enter a valid user name and password');
        } else {
            header('Location: http://google.com');
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываю ее перед запуском роутера в index файле:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Autoload.php');

Authentication::authenticate();
$router = new Router();
$router->run();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может я неправильно сделал аутентификацию или не в том месте вызываю? Даже если я ввожу правильные данные мне снова появляется форма для введения логина и пароля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует в условии указывать `and`, a не `or`

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!= "admin" and $_SERVER['PATH_AUTH_PW']!= "admin")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Вся проблема заключается в том, что вы при проверке используете `||` (что означает "или"), как уже указал n.osennij, вам необходимо проводить 'жёсткую' проверку используя `&&` (что означает "и"). Так же в условии вы можете ещё более 'ужесточить' сравнение используя `!==`:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!= "admin" && $_SERVER['PATH_AUTH_PW']!= "admin"){

} else{

}
```

ЗЫ. нет смысла ещё проверять на `isset`